# Broken Rails setup / pg gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2

UGH... I broke my (formerly functioning) Rails setup - under OS X Yosemite.  I did so using Homebrew to update my version of Git.  After getting Git where I want it, running 'rails c' gives these errors:

```
/Users/grogers/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.16.0/lib/pg.rb:4:in `require': dlopen(/Users/grogers/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.16.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.6.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /Users/grogers/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.16.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Users/grogers/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/pg-0.16.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle
```

Seeing the reference to pg_ext, I tried to verify pieces of my postgresql installation.  If I try 'gem install pg' or try to update the gem with bundler, I get this:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/grogers/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for pg_config... yes
Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

I'm probably making my problem worse, but I went back and redid a 'brew install postgres' but still get the same error.

Any help appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Did you also upgrade Postgresql via Homebrew? If not, what version of Postgres are you running, and how do you install it?

If you did upgrade your Postgres you'll need to rebuild the native bindings for the `pg` gem: `gem uninstall pg && gem install pg`.

Comment: Yes.  Did a 'brew install postgresql'.  At the moment that reports "Warning: postgresql-9.4.1 already installed" as I'd expect.  I just did a 'gem uninstall pg' which worked.  But after that 'gem install pg' still throws the same error.

Comment: The start of my problem may be missing Xcode install from last OS upgrade.  Trying to fix that up first.  I suspect further problems after, though...

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like your dynamic library path might not be correctly set. Be sure you have Xcode and the command line tools installed. `brew doctor` should tell you if you're missing anything in that regard. Also, be sure you're running in a clean shell so that your paths are all reloaded after the installs.

Comment: Yeah.  I've got myself in a bad place.  Xcode tools and command line are installed.  Machine rebooted for good measure.  Clean shells.  Same error from 'gem install pg'.  'brew doctor' complains of a ton of broken symlinks.  Too many to list.  Should I go with the 'brew prune' it suggests?